# How to get unknown constants from linear congruential generator

Tags: cryptanalysis, random-number-generator, congruence

I need to crack this linear congruential generator.

I have

$$X_{n+1}=a⋅X_n +b \pmod m$$

I know: $m=31,X_3=30,X_4=19,X_5=26$

How can I find $a,b$ and $X_0$?

---

I have got already the following equations:

$$26=a \cdot 19+b  \pmod{31}$$

$$19=a \cdot 30+b \pmod{31}$$

---

substruct 2 equations to get

$$7= -11 \cdot a  \pmod{31}$$
$$7= 20 \cdot a  \pmod{31}$$

the inverse of 20  is 14 in $\bmod 31$, $20 \cdot 14 = 1 \pmod{31}$.

$$7 \cdot 14= 14 \cdot 20 \cdot a  \pmod{31}$$

$$7 \cdot 14=  a  \pmod{31}$$

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. I don't see what you have tried here, but the name is the **hint**:  When you put given values you will get equations to solve. put $n=3$ and put $n=4$

Comment: Yes, I have edited the question

Comment: Now, substruct the two equations side by side to get rid of $b$ and solve for $a$

Comment: So I receive: 7=16a mod(31) is it correct?

Comment: nope $(26-19) = (19-30) a $

Comment: Ok, now I have 7=-11a+b
b = 7+11a ?

Comment: sorry no $b$'s, corrected mine. You can use MathJax in comments, too

Comment: Ok, so this means that I have $7 = -11a$. So $a = -7/11$. Correct?

Comment: no, we are working in modular arithmetic. $-11 = -11 +31 = 20 \pmod{31}$ , then find the inverse of $20$ that is $x \cdot 20 =1 \pmod{31}$. I hope you know modular arithmetic

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately I know only the basics of modular arithmetic.
So I understand that 19-30 = 20
So that means we have got the equation $7=20a$ -> $5=a$

Comment: You can use [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+20+mod+31), however learn [the algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse), too. $14 \cdot 20 = 1 \pmod{31}$

Comment: I'm sorry, I am a little confused. So now we have got the inverse of 20. But for which step do we need it?

Comment: Now, the rest for you...

Comment: Okay, I will try the rest! Thank you very much for your help!